# A very basic number sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

Predict the next members of the sequence below and explain what the relationship is.

2, 10, 101, 1211, 14321, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> $150145$

Because:

> Base-$2$ of $2$ is $10$,
>  Base-$3$ of $10$ is $101$,
>  Base-$4$ of $101$ is $1211$,
>  Base-$5$ of $1211$ is $14321$,
>  Base-$6$ of $14321$ is $150145$

Comment: Oooh - that's actually a clever number sequence!

Comment: A very "basic" one yep, but strangely never asked (to my knowledge).